# vm is running,DNS is connected no webpage

Tags: virtual-machines

Sorry, I'm a Noob. My VM's were stopped on GCP. I managed to get 1 VM up and running no problem by restarting it. I have tried to restart the other 2 VM's and they appear to be running but I've got no webpage. The external IP addresses are correct and the same at Google Domains, but still nothing.

Am I missing something in the backend of GCP? I've tried to SSH to restart Apache using this code:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

But I am getting this code back from the VM.

```
  Unmonitored apache
  Syntax OK
  /opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : apache not running
  Syntax OK
  (98)Address already in use: AH00073: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address [::]:80
  (98)Address already in use: AH00073: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address 0.0.0.0:80
  no listening sockets available, shutting down
  AH00015: Unable to open logs
  /opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd could not be started
  Monitored apache
```

Is this an easy fix or do I need to start afresh from a snapshot in a new VM instance? Some help would be appreciated, please.

Answer (score 0):

You have another process already listening on port 80. It could be anoher web server like `nginx` or a reverse proxy for example.

Try to use :

```
fuser -n tcp 80
```

to get the PID of the process listening on port 80.

Comment: Hi Yann, Many thanks for getting back to me. I tried that and this is the result I got:      james@wordpress-1-vm:~$ fuser -n tcp 80
-bash: fuser: command not found
james@wordpress-1-vm:~$

Comment: Unfortunately there is no fuser on that linux distribution. If you inspect `ps auxww` you should be able to figure out what process is using port 80.